# Validator if unique per 'server'

Tags: laravel, validation, unique, rules

I've a table persos (player) with id, pseudo, col3, col4, col5, col6, server_id.
And I want that save the persos id the pseudo (name) is unique in the server_id.

Ex: Player1 on server 1 and Player 1 on server 2 is possible, but not Player 2 on server 1 and Player 2 on server 1.

I've tried this, It's work for the 'pseudo' (name) but not per server:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'pseudo' => 'unique:persos,pseudo',
```

And if I add 'serveur' => 'unique:persos,serveur_id', it's not work because pseudo Player1 is taken, and the serveur1 also.

x2 : Play 1 - Serv 1 = NO 
x1: Play1 - Serv1 / x1 Play1 - Serv2 = OK
x1 Play1 -Serv1 / x1 Play2 - Serv 2 = OK

Thanks for your help

edit:

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'pseudo' => 'unique:persos,pseudo', 
            'level1' => 'required',
            'lvl2' => 'required',
            'lvl3' => 'required|max:10',
            'team' => 'max:30',
            'serveur' => 'required|unique:persos,serveur_id',

        ]);
if ($validator->fails()) {
             return redirect(route('perso.create'))
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput();
        }
        else
        {
            $perso = new Perso();
            $perso->pseudo = $request->get('pseudo');
            $perso->level1= $request->get('level1');
            $perso->lvl2= $request->get('lvl2');
            $perso->lvl3 = $request->get('lvl3');
            $perso->team= $request->get('team');
            $perso->user()->associate(Auth::id());
            $perso->serveur()->associate($request->get('serveur'));
            $perso->save();

            return $perso;
            return redirect(route('perso.frontIndex'));
        }
```

Comment: May I see your form input names and your store controller action. I may be able to help. tips:  you can use form request and bail your 'pseudo' => 'bail|required|unique:tablename' which will stop immediately.

Comment: @Madeny I've updated the post. The input names is same